# column chart color range for negative numbers and different color range for positive

Tags: highcharts

Trying to build a column chart with a range of colors for positive values and another range of colors for negative values.

for example, as much as my value is higher then the color is more "green", I want to add that if the number is less than zero, then as much it is small the color will be more "red".

[current situation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyI2S.png)

this is my code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    colorAxis: [{
            min: 0,
        maxColor: '#1FA37B',
        minColor: '#B6E4D5',
    },{
            max: 0,
        maxColor: '#F0BACC',
        minColor: '#D1315D',
    }],
        xAxis: [{
        categories: [
    "Oct 2021",
    "Nov 2021",
    "Dec 2021",
    "Sep 2021",
    "Aug 2021",
    "Jul 2021",
    "Jun 2021",
    "May 2021",
    "Apr 2021",
    "Mar 2021",
    "Feb 2021",
    "Jan 2021"
  ],
        reversed: false,
        labels: {
            step: 1
        }
    }],
  "series": [
    {
      "data": [[8.00],[18.00],[-8.00],[28.00],[38.00],[-18.00],[ 48.00],[58.00],[-28.00],[68.00],[78.00],[88.00]
      ],
      "type": "column",
      "showInLegend": false
    }
  ],
  "numberSuffix": "%",
  "categoriesFont": "Arial",
  "categoriesFontSize": "12px",
  "yAxisFontSize": "14px",
  "colorByPoint": false,
  "appendWidth": 10,
  "chartData": [{"date": "2021-10-01"},{"date": "2021-11-01"},{"date": "2021-12-01"},{"date": "2021-09-01"},{"date": "2021-08-01"},{"date": "2021-07-01"},{"date": "2021-06-01"},{"date": "2021-05-01"},{"date": "2021-04-01"},{"date": "2021-03-01"},{"date": "2021-02-01"},{"date": "2021-01-01"}]
});
```

and jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8569t3dr/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the `colorAxis` is defined per series, so if you want to have multiple `colorAxis` (one for positive values, one for negative) you need to split your series into two independent objects.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y4x36wmu/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.colorAxis